# Maven DependencyManagement not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I'm trying to use Maven's DependencyManagement feature to management my project dependencies across my sub projects.

My project structure is as follows:

ProjectA - packaging (pom)
 - Sub Project A - packaging (war)

Project A's pom file has the following

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And my sub pom has the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But the dependency isn't getting pulled in when I do this. If i change the parent pom and remove the dependency management tags, then the dependency gets pulled in fine.

The sub project pom has the parent setup, so it can 'see' the parent pom file.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use any of IDE, like IDEA? In case if getting the dependencies work for you, you'd need to make sure that the "internal" dependencies are up to date, by "Force project re-import". Other thing I could think of if that you have some profiles there. So make sure you're on the same profile.

Comment: show more of your sub-pom.

Comment: (Just a guess) Try a hard-coded version. manually fill in `${liquibase-version}`.

Answer (score -4):

please make sure following...

1. Check if the ${liquibase-version} is defined in the pom file.

example, in parent pom file add following tags with proper version number:

```
<properties>
    <liquibase-version>X.X.X</liquibase-version>
</properties>
```

2. make sure the child pom is pointing to parent properly. groupid, artifactid and version matches properly.

example, in child pom file add following tags with proper value which is exactly as it is defined parent pom file:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
    <groupId>xxx</groupId>
    <version>xxx</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: The whole point of `dependencyManagement` is supposed to be the fact that you *don't* have to put the version in the child pom.

Comment: This post is misleading, it misses the whole point of using dependency management.